# How to use pyew to scan PDF for malware?

Tags: python

I want to scan a few PDF files to see if they have malware in them. I have scanned with Spybot SnD and MalwareBytes and got it as clean.

However since `pyew` is dedicated to this, I want to scan the files with `pyew`. I downloaded  the `tar.gz` for my 32 bit windows from the project site but I do not know how to use it.

Kindly guide me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) for Windows.

See [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/installnotes.html#install_win) for installation instructions.

---

- Download the latest version of `pyew` for Windows([currently 2.0](https://code.google.com/p/pyew/downloads/detail?name=pyew-2.0-win32.tar.gz&can=2&q=)).
- Extract the files to a folder.
- Run the command prompt, navigate to folder of `pyew`, for example:

  `C:\Users\Username> cd downloads/pyew-2.0-win32`

  `C:\Users\Username\Downloads\pyew-2.0-win32> cd pyew-2.0`
- And finally run `pyew`:

  `C:\Users\Username\Downloads\pyew-2.0-win32\pyew-2.0> python pyew.py <filename>`

Comment: Got it running. What am I to do with the data that is output ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on pyew's source site goes over this in a fair amount of detail with examples and usecases. Check out the man pages at http://code.google.com/p/pyew/wiki/PDFAnalysis

Share and enjoy.